# Connect to Oracle via ODP.NET

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, visual-studio-2010, odp.net

I have installed oracle 12C ODP.NET in my server.i am using it to connect with my oracle 11g database.it is working fine in my Development server.But when i deployed my application to Live server, it shows "Unhandled exception". I dont know why it shows that.It worked on my development server.Is there any conflict between 32 or 64 bit? my application built on "Any CPU" mode and my server is 64 bit.Anyone can help ?

Comment: What exception did it throw? "Unhandled exception" is not very helpful.

Comment: It could also be an invalid login, you haven't been clear at all while explaining the problem! One thing is sure: if the application connects fine to a database, the reason why it does not connect to another database of the same version will not depend by the used libraries. Make sure you don't have problems connecting with other clients to that DB and find out what kind of exception it throwed.

Answer (score 0):

You simply have to copy dll **Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll** to same folder as your application. It does not matter if 32 bit or 64 mode, the managed driver works on both.

Comment: Or add the reference to the dll in your project, the file will be copied to the target folde.

Comment: @PabloCaballero - Yes, if set in reference properies accordingly. I don't know what the default is, but it may depend on installation on your development PC.